# Check MongoDB status in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I need to be able to run '`/etc/init.d/mongod status`' or '`service mongod status`' from wihtin a node js file, in order to store the response in the database.

When I run the above commands in the command line, I get the following response:

```
● mongod.service - SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-02-02 08:07:42 UTC; 3h 27min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 793 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1027 (mongod)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
           └─1027 /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

However, I want to include this status in an API response that I write. Therefore, when a user request my API, I want it to return the mongoDB status check as seen above.

I have tried the following ways:

router.get('/status', function(req, res) {

```
var databaseCheck = service mongod status // not sure how to do this
res.json({
    mongoResponse: '//to have the above status check response here'
});
```

});

I am new to all this, so any help would be appreciated. I may understand that my thinking is wrong - do let me know if there is a different way of doing this please

Comment: send a dummy request with ajax and if it fails you have the status?

Comment: Is there no way to do it from one file? I havent done ajax before

Answer (score 2):

Connect a database and then check connection like `db.serverConfig.isConnected()`. The below code is a full example.

```
const app = express();

let dbClient;
let db;
let collection;

MongoClient.connect(configuration.mongoDbUri, { useNewUrlParser: true, poolSize: 30 }, (error, client) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Connection failed for some reason. Err: ", error);
    return error;
  }
  db = client.db("myDB");
  dbClient = client;
  collection = db.collection('myCollection');
  app.locals.mongoDb = db;
});

app.get("/status", (req, res) => {
  if (db.serverConfig.isConnected()) {   
    console.log("db.serverConfig.isConnected :", db.serverConfig.isConnected());
    return res.send({ result: true});
  }
  return res.send({ result: false});
});

app.listen(configuration.app.port, error => {});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nodejs child-process module to run a shell command like you would from a terminal. In a terminal you would "service mongod status", in the nodejs child-process you would do the same by putting that command as an argument to the child-process execute function, like so:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('service mongod status', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

Comment: I get the following : SyntaxError: Unexpected token >    on this part ' stderr) => {'

Comment: you might have a nodejs version that doesn't support the new function arrow syntax, change the arrows with a normal javascript function

exec('service mongod status', function(error, stdout, stderr){...}));

If it gives you error about the ${stdout} and the rest of the variables with the $, just change that notation with the normal string concatenation like 
console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);

Make sure you use the right characters while writing this.. If you notice you can't just copypaste the function I wrote because it's not using ' but it's using `, which are different characters...

Answer (score 0):

Try code like this into you app:

```
db.serverConfig.isConnected();
```

Comment: Where `db` variable come from?

Comment: From method when you created the instance of the client and connected to MongoDB